# How do I configure AWS EC2 to respond to POST requests?

Tags: http, amazon-ec2

I just created a new EC2 instance and it is not responding to http POST request. It seems there should be some security settings to allow incoming/outgoing POST request but I am not sure how to set that up.

I edited the security setting to allows incoming for http (beyond initial SSH only) - attached image. But that doesn't help. I still can't do POST request.

Please suggest

[image]

Comment: Can you do get or other requests? Do you have any firewall rules in place on the machine? Anything in the web server logs?

Comment: @NickM I can do SSH. and I updated the config just now to be able to ping. But not http yet.

Comment: What OS you running?

Comment: @NickM it is ubuntu

Comment: And I assume you have a web server running and you can get a response to GET or PUT or other  requests, but not POST?

Comment: @NickM no, I have a service running and only testing POST.

Comment: See if GET requests work. Look in the server logs for any errors.

Comment: @NickM . no the GET is not even working. I think it is jut not reaching to the server. How do I see the logs?

Comment: It depends on what web server you use, for instance apache logs would be in /var/log/httpd.

Comment: @NickM Yes I am now facing a problem where all other request works except the post request in ec2. I tested it in both digital ocean and local server it is working perfectly but not in my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I had to allow inbound `All TCP` access in the security setting and that resolved the problem. Attached screenshot of how the security setting looks right now

[image]

Comment: There’s something wrong in your setup, you shouldn’t have to allow all traffic (a possible security problem) to connect to http which is on port 80.